# Ubuntu 14 doesn't auto-start mongodb at reboot

Tags: mongodb

I have a stock install of Ubuntu 14, installed a few weeks ago. I installed mongodb with apt-get. When I run

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

then the service runs correctly and I can access all the mongodb goodness. However, whenever I reboot it will not start automatically. I have tried running update.rc or whatever it is called, and it claims to run successfully however still no luck.

Is this a known issue? How can I diagnose it? And I guess, most importantly, how can I make it start at reboot?

Comment: Could you upload `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com